# How can I disable selection rectangle drawing in NSCollectionView?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nscollectionview

I have an `NSCollectionView` up and running fairly nicely with an `NSArrayController`.  My collection view items are configured to be multi-selectable and I am happy with the it.  However, when a mouse drag event occurs within the collection view, a selection rectangle is drawn.  How do I disable this selection rectangle drawing and still keep multiple selection in my `NSCollectionView`?  Thanks for any help!

Comment: I took another shot at figuring this one out.  I overrode mouseDragged: in both my NSCollectionView subclass and within my CollectionViewItem subclass.  I added breakpoints and discovered that neither are ever called during mouse drags.  Will have to see what other views are being used behind the scenes.

Comment: So you just want multi-select to work like it does now but not show any rectangle?

Comment: I would like to allow point and click, and shift|command click selection to work, without drawing the selection rectangle on drags.  Overriding mouseDragged:  did not help.  This behavior is had in Apple's Mail.app, for example, for its mail message subject collection view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSCollectionView` is a fairly opaque class, there are not too many ways you can easily modify its fundamental behaviour.

The drag actions appear to be handled by the private method `_performDragFromMouseDown:` rather than by overriding `mouseDragged:`. Exactly what the private method does I'm not sure.

The simple answer is that you can't change the selection appearance except by modifying private methods of `NSCollectionView`.

You may need to use a custom view instead of `NSCollectionView` if you must modify this behaviour.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I had tried overriding mouseDragged: with no success.

Answer (score 1):

With the latest `NSCollectionView` *(released 2015 I think?)* it calls `viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind` on the delegate to get the view for drawing the selection rectangle.

You can "catch" this situation by comparing `kind.rawValue` to `"NSCollectionElementKindSelectionRectIndicator"` in the delegate, and `return NSView()` **if you don't want it to draw**.

If you **do** want to draw it, return `collectionView.makeSupplementaryView(ofKind:` using a kind/identifier made manually using the rawValue of `"NSCollectionElementKindSelectionRectIndicator"`. These kinds/identifiers have been missing from the enums since 2015 I believe, and cause me grief everytime I implement NSCollectionView.

**Edit:** I looked up an old post I made about this on the Apple Developer Forums, and I mentioned that I had to guard against `numberOfSections == 0`, and `return NSView()` in that case.